# Compose aspectRatio Modifier not based on height

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to make a simple box (same height and width) based on a Column's wrapped height (two Text Composables). Using the aspectRatio Modifier property, the height is matching the full width, even with `matchHeightConstraintsFirst = true`. How do I get it to become a square from the wrap_content height?

[image]

```
@Composable
fun CompletionSquare(questionType: QuestionType, number: Int) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.gray))
            .padding(1.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.teal))
                .aspectRatio(matchHeightConstraintsFirst = true, ratio = 1.0f)
        ) {
            Text(text = questionType.type)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            Text(text = number.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have similar issue, have you figured it out?

Comment: @traninho check out my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I've just finished [the article about this exact problem](https://medium.com/@mmolosays/square-size-in-jetpack-compose-2d66457a83ea)

Here's the resulting [SquareSizeModifier.kt](https://gist.github.com/mmolosay/466b8f909fd30dbdf368da8972bb894f) file with a custom modifier.

Use it like this:

```kotlin
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 32.dp),
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = Color.LightGray)
            .squareSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        Text(text = "Correct")
        Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Text(text = "5")
    }
}
```

And here's the result:

[image]